# Solving an ODE by integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$, and that $f'(x) = g(x)$ on $(0,1]$. Can I conclude that for $x \in [0,1]$,
$$f(x) - f(0) = \int_0^x g(x) dx?$$
My issue is that we don't know that $f'(0) = g(0)$, but that shouldn't matter since the integral of two functions that differ on a set of measure zero are the same, right?

Also, what if all we knew was that $f$ was differentiable on $(0,1]$?

Comment: Is $x \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: Do you mean "we don't know that $f'(0) = g(0)$?  (note the prime!)

Comment: I've fixed the typos, sorry!

Comment: If you're talking about Riemman integration, your "right?" question is mistaken. Consider (i) the function that's $1$ on the rationals, $0$ on irrationals, and (ii) the function that's 0 everywhere. They agree away from a set of measure 0 (the rationals), but only the second is even integrable!

Comment: You've broken things during your fix; you really need $f'(0) = g(0)$, not $g'(0)$.

Comment: @JohnHughes shoot, sorry lol

Comment: @JohnHughes don't derivatives satisfy an intermediate value theorem? So the indicator of the rationals isn't a derivative

Comment: You statement "the integral of ..." doesn't say that the functions are derivatives. (They happen to be in this application, of course.) But since much of them point of the question is whether a function that's a derivative DOES have an integral, I doubt this makes a difference. Note that a derivative need not be continuous; it only need have the intermediate value property. @Bob Pego's answer gives a nice example.

Answer (score 2):

A technical problem that can make the conclusion fail, under just the assumptions you list, is that $g$ can fail to be Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$, so that the integral of $g$ is not well-defined! (A well-known type of example is the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(x^{-2})$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$.)

This is where the theory of the Kurzweil-Henstock integral shines, however. Assuming only as you do that $f:[0,1]\to R$ is differentiable at every point, necessarily the derivative $g$ is KH-integrable and the FTC holds.

The definition of the KH-integral is only a little different from the Riemann integral.  The book by Lee and Vyborny mentioned on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) is a nice place to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $x\in (0,1]$ and $f$ is $C^1$ we can rewrite 
$$
\int_0^xg(t)dt=\int_0^xf'(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)
$$
with the first step by assumption and the second step by the FTC.